# Why does visual studio ignore the tlb filename specified in the project file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, typelib

I'm in the process of upgrading a Visual C++ 6 project to Visual Studio 2010, and I've been replacing the post-compile steps of copying files to a common location with having the output file put directly in the final location. However, for the *.tlb files that are being generated, there is an option (in project properties -> MIDL -> Output) to specify the filename. When I put the full path there, it looks reasonable in the command line (says /tlb "full\path\to\filename.tlb"). However, when it actually compiles, the file doesn't get put in the right place, and the command that was executed according to the log was /tlb ".\filename.tlb"). I'm hesitant to specify the path as the output directory, because then it will output the XXX_i.c and XXX.h files into that location as well, which isn't what I want.

Is there any way to get Visual Studio to respect the setting I actually put in the option, instead of doing what it wants?

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem as well and I finally found out why. Even though this question is a bit old, since it's still open I'll post my solution...

In addition to the MIDL settings under the project properties, there's the same settings under the IDL file itself. Just right-click the IDL file -> Properties -> MIDL -> Output.

This did it for me. Seems illogical, though.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into same situation so I specified the output file as a relative path and it generated the tlb file in the correct location instead of the default location